# Serializing custom modules together with object in python

Tags: python, serialization, pickle, python-module, dill

**Problem**

Let's say I have this module named `custom_module`:

```
class CustomClass:
    pass
```

And I use this class in a script that serializes an object of the class I defined in `custom_module`:

```
import cloudpickle
import custom_module as cm

custom_object = cm.CustomClass()
with open('filename.pkl', 'wb') as file:
    cloudpickle.dump(custom_object, file)
```

I copy this pickle file to another environment and load it with another script:

```
import cloudpickle

with open('filename.pkl', 'rb') as file:
    custom_object = cloudpickle.load(file)
```

That would yield this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "loader.py", line 4, in <module>
    custom_object = cloudpickle.load(file)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'custom_module'
```

---

**Awkward solution**

As a workaround it is possible to read and execute everything that is in `custom_module` in my script:

```
exec(open(path.join('custom_module.py')).read())
```

but that looks really weird and I can't use CustomClass as `cm.CustomClass`. Is there any other solution that doesn't involve copying all the code in the first environment to the second?

Answer (score 1):

You can solve the problem by reimplement `CustomClass` in `custom_module` the following way:

```py
def __CustomClass():
    class CustomeClass:
        ... # Your implementaion here
    return CustomeClass

CustomClass = __CustomClass()
```

The error will gone if you are lucky enough. If not, you need to dive into `CustomClass` to find out other functions or classes that are defined in other local modules, and reimplement them using the same method.

You can find more detail in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75292769/). You may also use `cloudpickle.register_pickle_by_value` to solve the issue, but it is labeled as an experimental feature.